# Javascript Regex pattern: Find the secret word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to identify the secret word in the given string. which is surrounded by each letter with `P`, `K`.

This is code I wrote to identify the words surrounded by `P`, `K`.

```js
var text = "PAKPPKPPKPLKPEK";
var pattern = /[^P.K]/g;
var arraytext = text.match(pattern);
console.log(arraytext);
```

I am expecting output as `["A", "P", "P", "L", "E"]` instead I am getting as like this `["A", "L", "E"]`.

Comment: Grab all Group 1 values with `/P(.)K/g`

Comment: you should check if . is expanded or not, usually some metacharacters loose their meaning inside '[]'.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `[^P.K]` is a negated charater class which will match any char except P K or a dot which will for the current data give you A L and E.

You could use a capturing group and use that in the replacement to get APPLE or get the group values separately where the dot means any character except a newline.

```
P(.)K
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GthtPH/1)

If you want to use a character class and be real specific you could also use `P([A-Z])K`

```js
const regex = /P(.)K/g;
const str = `PAKPPKPPKPLKPEK`;
const subst = `$1`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

For example to get the values in an array

```js
const regex = /P(.)K/g;
const str = `PAKPPKPPKPLKPEK`;
let m;

let result = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  result.push(m[1])
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get any character between `P` and `K` then using slice getting only the character in the middle but i think there is way more better solution.

```js
var text = "PAKPPKPPKPLKPEK";
var pattern = /P[a-zA-Z]K/g;
var arraytext = text.match(pattern).map(el => el.slice(1, 2));
console.log(arraytext);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^P.K]` is a negated character class, and will match one character that is not `P`, `.`, or `K`. This will ignore the `P` in `APPLE`. Maybe something like this instead?

`P(\w)K`

This will match one word character between `P` and `K`. You'll need to slice the "P" and "k" away from each letter, but you'll get the match you're looking for.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9T9REX/1/)